# Android: open Map intent with directions with two points

Tags: android, google-maps

How to open map intent with directions?

I know about

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(String.format(Locale.US, "geo:%.8f,%.8f", latitude, longitude)));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select an application"));
```

This code works fine for ONE point. But I want to show dialog with *ALL* map-applications, and open directions from point A to point B with any application (Google Map, Citymapper, web browser, etc).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

have you tried this

```
String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr="+latitude1+","+longitude1+"&daddr="+latitude2+","+longitude2;
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select an application"));
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it with other applications (1-2 days), because "Citymapper" not works for me (crash), "Ynadex Maps" (does not support this api?) not works too.

Comment: First and best answer. +50.

Comment: this should be surround with try/catch as it will be an exception if no activity found to handle request!

Comment: Is there any way to display Polyline on Google Map via Intent?

Comment: I want all location navigation based app show not just google

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("geo:" + latitude1 + "," + longitude1 + "?q=" + Uri.encode(latitude2 + "," + longitude2 + "(" +Label+ ")"));
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This was the answer that I was looking for. Lately, "http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr..." opens GMaps directly even if I use Intent.createChooser

Comment: just load latitude2 and longitude2  as the destination
and ignore first corrdinates

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't use an universal URI to represent **two** geo points.

You can specify a single point and pass it to the chooser like:

```
String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:%f,%f", lat, lng);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select your maps app"));
```

However to get directions, unfortunately, you'll need to use:

**Single URL:**

The best choice in my opinion. You should use a single map supplier and use its URL as the URI. That way the directions you get are consistent, compatible with multiple devices and most importantly easy to use/get.

**Plain old URLs:**

You can use different URL's for different map suppliers.

For example, *Citymapper*:

```
https://citymapper.com/london/superrouter?start=LAT_START,LNG_START&end=LAT_END,LNG_END
```

However others aren't that friendly, e.g. *Yandex*:

```
http://maps.yandex.com/?rtext=59.326460%2C12.699889~57.386826%2C12.348327&sll=12.941588%2C56.517713&sspn=34.716797%2C12.029728&rtm=atm&source=route&ll=12.941588%2C56.517713&spn=34.716797%2C12.029728&z=6&l=map
```

Maybe you can decode that url yourself :)

**Integrated Maps API**

Integrate e.g. Google Maps API into your app and show the directions from there.
You would need to get directions in the format of lat-lng points from the Directions API in a JSON format. Then you would use those points to draw a polyline.

Comment: Thanks, I know it :) I need an universal method, see Foursquare

Comment: @monyag I've checked it out and as I said it's not using an universal URI because there isn't one. It's just providing a Google Maps URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a URL in the format

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=[latitude1], [longitude1]&daddr=[latitude2], [longitude2]
```

Where [latitude1] and [longitude1] are the latitude and longitude for the start point, and likewise [latitude2] and [longitude2] are the end point, and set it as a String

```
Intent navigationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(navigationUrlOfMap));
intent.setClassName("com.Google.Android.apps.maps", "com.Google.Android.maps.MapsActivity");
 startActivity(intent);
```

Or you can also use this also

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select an application"));
```

If you want to set chooser application